# Geolocation precision

Tags: geolocation

When I do geolocation from my site, I only get results to 4 decimal places, but on a site I did at school I got results to 7 decimal places?  Is this difference in accuracy due to having different web hosts?

Answer (score 2):

it's not about web hosting.
Here are some method which might be used to determine your location.

1. GPS (Global Positioning System) - This happen for smartphone / anything which has GPS inside. If you smartphone with GPS capabilities, but have accuracy above 100 (poor) try to turn on or sett your location services.
2. Cellphone triangulation - This happen if you use a wireless modem or phone without GPS chip built in it.
3. WiFi Positioning System - If you are indoor, and using Wifi
4. IP Address Location - This one will detects your location based on neareset Public IP Address on your devices, (can be your computer, or the router, or your ISP provider)

Above are based on Some of my work related to geolocation like in here ([My Current Location](http://mycurrentlocation.net/) )

Answer (score 0):

No. Turn on your notebook / tablet wireless or GPS before access your geolocation page will increase precision.

Answer (score 0):

Web host has nothing to do with the Geolocation precision. Instead, it depends on the type of accessibility you gave to the device to access your location.

Ways to improve location accuracy:

1. GPS: This uses satellites and knows your location up to around 20 meters. Note: When you're inside buildings or underground, the GPS is sometimes inaccurate.
2. Wi-Fi: The location of nearby Wi-Fi networks helps Maps know where you are.
3. Cell tower: Your connection to a cellular network can be accurate up to a few thousand meters.
4. Turn on high-accuracy mode - https://youtu.be/XqoSCrT62Hg

I have been actively using Google API for geolocation accuracy on my site. Do have a look if you need to know how I am using it on [My Location Right Now](https://mylocationrightnow.com/)